# performance of large number calculations in python (python 2.7.3 and .net 4.0)

Tags: python, .net

There is a lot of general questions about python performance in comparison to other languages.
I've got more specific example:
There are two simple functions wrote in python an c#, both checking if int number is prime.

python:

```
import time

def is_prime(n):
    num =n/2
    while num >1:
        if n % num ==0:
            return 0
        num-=1
    return 1

start = time.clock()
probably_prime = is_prime(2147483629)
elapsed = (time.clock() - start)
print 'time : '+str(elapsed)
```

and
C#:

```
 using System.Diagnostics;

 public static bool IsPrime(int n)
        {
            int num = n/2;
            while(num >1)
            {
                if(n%num ==0)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                num-=1;
            }
            return true;
        }
 Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
 sw.Start();
 bool result = Functions.IsPrime(2147483629);
 sw.Stop();
 Console.WriteLine("time: {0}", sw.Elapsed);
```

And times ( which are surprise for me as a begginer in python:)):

Python: 121s; 
c#: 6s

Could You explain where does this big diffrence come from ?

Comment: What exactly is surprising about this? Compiled languages can forgo type checks, dynamic languages check for types and the availability of hook methods every single time.

Comment: the degree of difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without type information, Python spends a lot more time looking up what to do rather than doing it in that big while loop.

You can run this faster with Python syntax in a couple of ways:

1) Use PyPy --- it watches how the code is being run, notices the types, and replaces the slow-lookups with fast machine code on the fly --- it's pretty cool

2) Use Numba --- this works with standard CPython run-time and so can be used with your favorite Python extension.  By adding a decorator you pre-compile the function to machine-code when it gets called with "typed" things (like integers).

I couldn't do the PyPy timings, but on my system the Python code took about 180s and the numba-code took about 14s.

Here is the numba-code:

```
import numba
@numba.jit(numba.bool_(numba.int64), nopython=True)
def is_prime(n):
    num =n/2
    while num >1:
       if n % num ==0:
            return 0
        num-=1
    return 1
```